# "Adding" a value to a tuple?

Tags: julia

I am attempting to represent dice rolls in Julia. I am generating all the rolls of a `n`d`sides` with

```
sort(collect(product(repeated(1:sides, n)...)), by=sum)
```

This produces something like:

```
[(1,1),(2,1),(1,2),(3,1),(2,2),(1,3),(4,1),(3,2),(2,3),(1,4)  …  (6,3),(5,4),(4,5),(3,6),(6,4),(5,5),(4,6),(6,5),(5,6),(6,6)]
```

I then want to be able to reasonably modify those tuples to represent things like dropping the lowest value in the roll or adding a constant number, etc., e.g., converting `(2,5)` into `(10,2,5)` or `(5,)`.

Does Julia provide nice functions to easily modify (not necessarily in-place) n-tuples or will it be simpler to move to a different structure to represent the rolls?

Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest using a different data structure. Tuples do not have any `setindex!` methods, which is what Julia uses to modify containers. A vector (really `Array{Int, 1}`) would be quite straightforward as you could use `push!` and `pop!` to add and delete things.

Answer (score 5):

Tuples are immutable, so you can't modify them in-place. There is very good support for other mutable data structures, so there aren't many methods that take a tuple and return a new, slightly modified copy.  One way to do this is by splatting a section of the old tuple into a new tuple, so, for example, to create a new tuple like an existing tuple `t` but with the first element set to `5`, you would write: `tuple(5, t[2:end]...)`.  But that's awkward, and there are much better solutions.

As spencerlyon2 suggests in his comment, a one dimensional `Array{Int,1}` is a great place to start.  You can take a look at the [Data Structures](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/stdlib/collections/) manual page to get an idea of the kinds of operations you can use; one-dimensional Arrays are iterable, indexable, and support the dequeue interface.

Depending upon how important performance is and how much work you're doing, it may be worthwhile to create your own data structure. You'll be able to add your own, specific methods (e.g., `reroll!`) for that type. And by taking advantage of some of the domain restrictions (e.g., if you only ever want to have a limited number of dice rolls), you may be able to beat the performance of the general `Array`.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a new tuple based on spreading or slicing another:

```
 julia> b = (2,5)
 (2, 5)

 julia> (10, b...)
 (10, 2, 5)

 julia> b[2:end]
 (5,)
```